# Smooth scroll recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, smooth-scrolling

I have a `Recyclerview` which contains `ratingbar` in `list_items.xml`

on completion of the rating of one item in `Recyclerview` I scroll to another item of `Recyclerview` automatically

The scrolling is very fast , user couldn't know that it is scrolled.

I implemented smooth scroll , but not working properly, 
**first scroll of 2nd item is smooth (1st is already displayed ), but other items scroll is fast**

LinearLayoutSmoothScroll.java

```
public class LinearLayoutSmoothScroll extends LinearLayoutManager {
        private static final float MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = 100f;
        private Context mContext;

        public LinearLayoutSmoothScroll(Context context) {
                super(context);
                mContext=context;
        }

        public LinearLayoutSmoothScroll(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
                super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
                mContext=context;
        }

        public LinearLayoutSmoothScroll(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
                super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
                mContext=context;
        }
        @Override
        public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                           RecyclerView.State state, final int position) {

                LinearSmoothScroller smoothScroller =
                        new LinearSmoothScroller(mContext) {

                                //This controls the direction in which smoothScroll looks
                                //for your view
                                @Override
                                public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition
                                (int targetPosition) {
                                        return LinearLayoutSmoothScroll.this
                                                .computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
                                }

                                //This returns the milliseconds it takes to
                                //scroll one pixel.
                                @Override
                                protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel
                                (DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
                                        return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH/displayMetrics.densityDpi;
                                }
                        };

                smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
                startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
        }
}
```

usage :

```
layoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(rvSurvey,new RecyclerView.State(),new_position);
```